# Is it possible to add an anchor to a FORM post/get?

Tags: html, forms, input, submit

I noticed that in Firefox I can add a #MyAnchor tag to the action attribute like...

```
<form action="#MyAnchor">
   <input type="text" name="a" />
   <input type="text" name="b" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and when the form is submitted, the anchor automatically shows up in the URL like

mypage.aspx?a=1&b=2#MyAnchor

However, this doesn't work on IE.  Is there anyway I can find a happy medium for both browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a guess, but have you tried using the page + the anchor name.

```
<form action="mypage.aspx#MyAnchor">
```

Comment: What version of IE are you testing this on?

Comment: Are you performing any actions in javascript, or on postback?

Answer (score 2):

I've used this to retain the fragment across postbacks:

```
    var f = document.forms[0];
    var index = f.action.indexOf("#");
    if(index>0)
        f.action = f.action.substr(0,index) + "#" + tabId;
    else
        f.action += "#" + tabId;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can deal with this either on the client side or on the server side:

On the server side: add a hidden  element with the anchor as the value and do a redirect on an URL build on the server.

On the client side: jQuery for instance allows you to serialize a form's parameters into a URL; you would just need to append the anchor and assign this to window.location.