# How can I make a form submit button also redirect to a specific div in the page ?

Tags: php, javascript, slider, anchor, contact-form

The website i'm doing is made of a fullscreen slider, with 4 different panels.

The fourth panel contains a php contact form. When I submit the form, it reloads the page from the first slider, so the user can't see the results (message sent, or any error) which are in the fourth panel, with the form.

Is there any way I can make the submit button also redirect to the div containing the form ?

Here is the basic markup, with the php script used :

```
<div id="container">

<div id="div1">
<div class="content">...</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
<div class="content">...</div>
</div>

<div id="div3">
<div class="content">...</div>
</div>

<div id="div4">
<div class="content">
                <form method="post" action="index.php">

                    <label>Nom</label>
                    <input class="small" name="name" placeholder="Name">

                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input class="small" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">

                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea class="small" name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>

                    <label>What's the best burger ever (antispam)</label>
                    <input class="small" name="human" placeholder="type the right answer">

                    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="send">

                </form>

<?php
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $from = 'From: ...'; 
    $to = 'johndoe@gmail.com'; 
    $subject = 'New message';
    $human = $_POST['human'];

    $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '') {
        if ($human == 'bacon burger') {              
            if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
            echo '<div class="alert green"><p>Message sent!</p></div>';
        } else { 
            echo '<div class="alert red"><p>An error occured. Go back and try again.</p></div>'; 
        } 
    } else if ($_POST['submit'] && $human != 'bacon burger') {
        echo '<div class="alert red"><p>You answered wrong to the antispam question.</p></div>';
    }
    } else {
        echo '<div class="alert red"><p>You have to fill in all fields !</p></div>';
    }
}
?>

</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: I don't know PHP, but how about anchors?  Just set on in your div and than call some javascript at the begining of your page to tak you to it.

Comment: is it possible for you to use any javascript library in this project? jQuery for example to make your form submiting without page reload? - it's called an AJAX technology

Comment: simplest tutorial - http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/ and a demo - http://demos.net.tutsplus.com/contactform/

Comment: maybe you'll find a solution there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693545/is-it-possible-to-add-an-anchor-to-a-form-post-get

Comment: Seems like a good way to go as well, I will look after this. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding anchor id to `action` url:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php#div4">
```

Comment: @tostrsp It works, if it is plain html. Don't you use javascript to build the slider? Or is your slider-plugin able to process this?

Comment: Yes, the slider plugin I use includes an option to link a panel to an anchor. So it works fine, even if there is still a small glitch since the page still reloads from #div1 and then go to #div4. As it loads in maybe 0.3s, it results in some clipping due to the fast moving into the page. I guess the only way to go through this is to use some ajax to prevent page reloading.

Comment: @tostrsp or you could reorder your divs serverside when a fragment indentifier is present.