# Using page anchor on form submit with method=get

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a web page with a large form that re-calls itself on submit. It uses Method=Get. I am trying to make the page redisplay itself at an anchor below the form where the output is instead of at the top of the page.

I have read lots of places that say to simply add the #xxx to the end of the action. eg.

```
<form method="get" action="index.php#output">
```

eg. see [This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10800212/how-can-i-make-a-form-submit-button-also-redirect-to-a-specific-div-in-the-page)

They may well work for Method=Post but it does not work for Method=Get. Tried on IE, Chrome and Firefox.

The URL ends up looking like this:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php#output?name=jones&place=someplace
```

and no output is produced. If I hack the URL to look like this then it works perfectly:

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?name=jones&place=someplace#output
```

Is there any way of making it work please? Maybe with Javascript onSubmit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET is GET and POST is POST. They are built for its own usage, not for page display logic.

GET is meant to retrieve some resource from server. POST is meant to add some resource to server.

A common case to use GET in form is a search form. You case looks similar. So, I do not suggest your hacking it as POST just for displaying something.

If you want to display the submit result in same page, you can consider using jQuery's `$.get` to hijack form submission, and append the result to DOM after success, though that's another question.

Comment: You mean all of those millions of pages out there that use method=get for form submission got it wrong?

Comment: @user2605793, using GET as form method to retrieve something is totally correct, such as a search form. However, if the form is to add something, say, submission of a comment, using GET is totally wrong.