# Adding anchor point in form on submit?

Tags: html, anchor

I am using a script called Advanced Poll which is working great. However I have a small "cosmetic" problem, which I cannot solve.

The poll is located on the lower right side of my website. But after someone submits his or her vote, you are pushed back to the top of the page instead of focussing on the poll (lower right).

Normally with normal html you can fix this easily by adding an anchor point and a link, however because this is form, I don't understand how to do it correctly. So it 'reloads' the page back at the poll section after submitting a vote, instead of scrolling down again.

I tried fooling around a bit with the HTML myself, however no luck. It starts back at the top of the website, instead of staying around the poll-area.

I added the code below, above the poll section:

```
<a name="backtopoll"></a>
```

And I added:

```
 #backtopoll
```

to:

```
<a href="$this->form_forward?action=results&amp;poll_ident=$poll_id" class="link link-indent fright">$pollvars[result_text]</a>
```

Which results in:

```
 <a href="$this->form_forward?action=results&amp;poll_ident=$poll_id#backtopoll" class="link link-indent fright">$pollvars[result_text]</a>
```

But that didn't work. As soon as I click on submit vote, my vote is cast and I find myself back at the top of the website again, instead of reloading the page at the poll-section. :(

What am I doing wrong here...?

//update

Adding / changing it to:

```
 <a id="backtopoll"></a>
```

As Sibu stated, didn't work.

//anotherupdate

Maybe I can do the same with jQuery or JS on the page?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to add an anchor to a FORM post/get?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693545/is-it-possible-to-add-an-anchor-to-a-form-post-get)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind I fixed it myself by using the information described here: [Is it possible to add an anchor to a FORM post/get?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693545/is-it-possible-to-add-an-anchor-to-a-form-post-get)

```
<form action="mypage.aspx#MyAnchor">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way,# is used for id not name

```
<a id ="backtopoll"></a>
```

Comment: Same result, still goes back to the top of the page. :(

Comment: It loads index.php

The original url (in the poll submit button) is:

    <a href="$this->form_forward?action=results&amp;poll_ident=$poll_id" class="link link-indent fright">$pollvars[result_text]</a>

Comment: @HudsonHawk you need to show more code of yours,which function is called

Comment: <a id="backtopoll"></a>
<div>$question</div>
<form method="post" action="$this->form_forward">

<div><input type="radio" name="option_id" value="$data[option_id]">$data[option_text]</div>

<input type="hidden" name="action" value="vote">
<input type="hidden" name="poll_ident" value="$poll_id">

<div style=padding-top:12px;padding-bottom:30px;>
<div style="float:left;"><input type="submit" value="$pollvars[vote_button]" class="input"></div>
<a href="$this->form_forward?action=results&amp#backtopoll;poll_ident=$poll_id" class="link link-indent fright">$pollvars[result_text]</a>
</div>

Comment: As mentioned in the first post; it's Advanced Poll 2.09

Comment: Hello... Are you still here Sibu?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it is ugly to work with anchors in forms. Working with **.focus()** lets you position the page much more easily.